# How many years is the harvest moon back to nature going on? What happens after the third year?

Tags: harvest-moon-back-to-nature

How many years is the [harvest moon back to nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvest_Moon:_Back_to_Nature) going on? What happens after the third year?

I heard you can go to a city or whatever it is after finishing the third year but as far as I can remember, nothing happened!.
I played this game almost more than 17 years ago But I never understood what would happen after the third year.

Comment: are you asking how to get past the 3rd year? or if there is more game after that? because the 3rd year is just a gate, the game still continues afterward.

Comment: @Rapitor
Yes, I want to know is there more game after that?
I really thought I was going to waste time after three years. I did not know that the 3rd year is just a gate, the game still continues afterward.

Comment: @Rapitor You can keep playing but it gets boring because baby never grows and nobody every change after 5 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no new city available after three years. After three years, a cutscene will trigger where the mayor checks on your progress. If you have done enough to unlock the good end, then a happy cutscene praising your achievements will play, the [credits will roll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4U-K1NnZ4Y), and  and you will be allowed to continue playing the game in the same town as before. You can then build your farm up further and continue to unlock new events.

Otherwise, the mayor will tell you that you have to leave town, and [the bad ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn0Y166bXN4) will unlock. This bad ending has you leaving, but you don't then unlock a city to play in or anything like that.

Comment: Does This Game Have An End? 
Despite the goal of three years (gaining the town's approval) you get to continue playing for as many years as you'd like.

Comment: @user221105 most harvest moon/story of season games don't have an ending(wonderful life is the only outlier I know of, ending at 10 years), and you just continue on until you get bored of the yearly routine or finished any goal you set out to achieve. this included